# Increase spacing between icon and cursor in search bar Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

Increase spacing between icon and cursor in search bar

So I want to add a space between the searchIcon and the text that the user enters as it's too close to one another.

[image]

Comment: Hello again! Please take a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Could you please post your code / IB layout? You haven't given us much to go on.

Comment: Look at `searchTextPositionAdjustment` for `UISearchBar` if all you want to do is shift the position of the search text

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Take a look at the [UISearchBar Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISearchBar/searchTextPositionAdjustment) by Apple and look for `searchTextPositionAdjustment`.

To create a gap of 10 pixels between the icon and the text you could do the following in your code:
`searchBar.searchTextPositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(10.0f, 0.0f);`

Comment: Thanks allot I was looking at the wrong stuff the whole time :)